# Why does the narrator ask to "give me some time" in "Brand New Day" by Ryan Star?

Tags: song-lyrics, ryan-star

From *Brand New Day* by Ryan Star contains the following lyrics:

> I stayed in one place for too long
>   Gotta get on the run again
>   I saw the one thing that I want
>   Hell bent, get outta bed
>   I'm throwing rocks at your window
>   You're tying the bed sheets together
>   They say we are dreaming too big
>   I say this town's too small
>
> Dream
>   Send me a sign
>   **Turn back the clock
>
>   Give me some time**
>
>   I need to break out
>   And make a new name
>   Let's open our eyes
>   To the brand new day

Why does the narrator need more time? Time for what? And who is he asking to give him more time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Turning back the clock," literally, would be to allow the narrator to re-live those hours/days/etc. It would give the narrator time.

"I stayed in one place too long" gives the sense of wasted time — that the narrator is accustomed to constant movement, not putting down roots — and "give me some time" might mean the person wishes he could re-live some of the time he spent "in one place" and use it to go somewhere else.

Since turning back time is a physical impossibility, he's not addressing any real person; it's just a philosophical cry into the wind.

Comment: 'Turning back the clock' *figuratively* would allow the narrator to relive etc... perhaps, rather than 'literally'?  I turned back my clocks at the weekend , it shifted my day by an hour but i didn't get to rewind the stuff I'd done. :)